# base64 decode French characters

Tags: php, xml, encoding, character-encoding

We are getting base64 encoded (XML) data from a third party. If the XML data is in English, everything works fine, I am able do base64 decode, and parse the XML. If the XML is all lower case French characters, everything works fine. But if the xml data contains upper case French characters (like &Agrave), if I do base64 decode and try to parse it, the parser fails. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide more info how the parser files, what error messages you get, etc.

Comment: The problem is obviously with the parser ... what tool are you using?

Comment: XML character encoding is UTF-8. This is what I am doing to parse the xml.

Comment: $data = base64_decode($data); $xml = simplexml_load_string($data); The value of $xml is 0.

Comment: Shouldn't this print Â?                        
            $str = 'Test: Â';
            echo '<br/>TEXT: ' . $str;
            echo '<br/>BASE64 ENCODED TEXT: ' . base64_encode($str);
            echo '<br/>BASE64 DECODED TEXT: ' . base64_decode(base64_encode($str));base64_decode(base64_encode($str));

Comment: Have you run the generated XML through a XML validator?  You could also try converting the encoded characters before running simplexml_load_string via iconv ... http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 3):

Base64 is a method to encode 8-bit binary data using 7-bits/US-ASCII charachters. After the Base64 decode you should have a standard XML file.
Probably this XML file contains illegal characters, or does not correctly specify the character encoding it uses.

You mention `&Agrave;`, an HTML-specific (not-XML) representation of À. If the XML contains the HTML encoded string `&Agrave;`, there should also be a reference in the XML to an entity table specifying how to decode that string.

Alternatively, if your XML contains the À character directly, encoded using (for example) the ISO-8859-1 character set, either your XML should specify this encoding (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`), or you should specify it yourself when decoding it.
Failing that, the parser may assume (e.g) UTF-8 encoding is used, and will fail when trying to decode the À.

The exact error message should tell you what the problem is.

[update: À directly]:
Sounds like the XML is invalid then; that they say UTF-8 but are actually using a different encoding. Check the XML bytes (after the base 64 decode) for this; if the À is encoded as one byte, it is definitely not UTF-8.

[update: how to fix?] If they incorrectly specify it in the XML header, they should really replace the false header (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`) with the correct one (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>`).
If they don't specify anything, it looks like the [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function may be your best bet. I haven't really needed it, so I'm not 100 % sure about this, but looks like you could use: $data = iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $data) after the base64_decode and before the simplexml_load_string. I don't know of a way to specify the encoding directly while decoding the XML.

I'm not really experienced with the PHP specifics of character encoding, so I'm not giving any guarantees...

Comment: They are using the French character À directly. They are setting the xml encoding to UTF-8. I am trying to parse the xml data like this, $xml = simplexml_load_string($data). The value of $xml is 0 after executing this line.

Comment: Here is a sample xml. The encoded data I get from them (java app) is different than the encoded string I get back from PHP base64_encode($xmlstr). 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><feed><title><![CDATA[Test French character: À]]></title></feed>

Comment: Can you check if the À is encoded as bytes 0xC3 0x80 (utf-8) or as 0xC0 (iso-8859-1)?

Comment: You mean, like ord($str[$i])?

Comment: I think I am missing something. Encoded data looks something like this - 'PD94bWwgdmVyc...'. If I do echo ord($str[$i]) on this encoded string, it prints out 80, 68, 57,..., the ascii characters for P,D,9. I don't think this is what you want me to try?

Comment: no, you should do the base64_decode first, then the ord($str[$i])

Comment: You are right. They said UTF-8, but it turns out they are using Win-1252 encoding. How do I specify Win-1252 when decoding?

Comment: They are using Win-1252 encoding, but the xml header still says <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>. Should the header be changed as well?

Comment: I did iconv, and À shows up as Ãƒ?  If I do ord($str[$i]), I get Ã = 195
ƒ = 131
? = 63

Answer (score 1):

What's the XML character encoding? Maybe it's not `UTF-8` and your parser is trying to parse the `XML` string as `UTF-8`.